# ssh configure rsa public key login without input password failed

Tags: sshd

I have two remote servers host1 and host2. I login them with the same user "sftp". I configure ssh setting to login without password. It works with host1, but don't work with host2. The difference between host1 and host2 is that the user login home directory is under /data/home/sftp/ not /home/sftp/ on the host2. I had tried to modify the AuthorizedKeyFile to  "%h/.ssh/authorized_keys", "/data/home/sftp/.ssh/authorized_keys" and "/data/home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys", but none of them works. when I create a new user "test" with login home directory in "/home/test", it can login without password. can someone give me advice, thank a lot.

Comment: Default is `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2`  which means that it should pick up the home directory automatically and append the `.ssh/...` parts  Does `host2` use a `chroot` jail or similar?

Comment: I checked there is no chroot jail. The output of "ls -ld /" is "dr-xr-xr-x. 26 root root 4096 Jul 26 14:19 /" @ivanivan

Comment: when I use "/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 22" restart sshd on host2, I can login without password, but it requires password to login again after "service sshd restart"